# Nested ASP.NET activities for independent requests

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, etw, perfview

I have a trace like this done by perfview:

[image: perfview trace]

It should be taken with 'Thread time' switch. What I don't understand is why the activities are nested like this. I'm pretty sure that requests for the files are independently made by a browser and there is no relation between them. Basically the files should be cached. So the byte array is just copied asynchronously to the output stream.

- **Why are the activities nested?**
- **Also what might that UNKNOWN_ASYNC in mycontext mean?**

---

Edit: added sshot from production with much less usage.

[image: production server]

I suspect that my question is somehow related to performance testing. I'll try to reproduce this behaviour under a load.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2015/09/14/exploring-eventsource-activity-correlation-and-causation-features/

Comment: I know that activities can nest. But that's completely different to nested requests. Requests generally are not supposed to nest...

Comment: @stej could you share the Events views with the following events selected for your process: AspNetTrace/AspNetReq/Start, AspNetTrace/AspNetReq/Stop

Comment: I suspect that it is somehow related to performance testing - when I capture events at production server right now, there is no such behaviour. I aded the sshot of Thread Time with StartStop activities to the question.

Comment: Still - how can I track what's behind the UNKNOWN_ASYNC?

Comment: @stej have you tried looking at the "Threads with ready stacks" view limiting the time range for the specific UNKNOWN_ASYNC?

Comment: I made a new measurement and see UNKNOWN_ASYNC again. Honestly, I don't know how it relates to Threads with ready stacks view. I tried to compare, but there is no information about thread around the UNKNOWN_ASYNC...